# Asp.net core migration:The selection cannot be targeted by this project type. Create a new non-portable project to target it

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, asp.net-core

I have web project asp.net core and when I referenced another project which has dependency on Newtonsoft.Json (7.0). The solution stopped compiling and Newtonsoft.Json was not resolved.

I updated Newtonsoft to 9.0,1 and warning stayed on Newtonsoft. 
I tried to remove other targets and just keep asp.net core 1.0. When I deselected other target, the change target screen shows this message " the selection cannot be targeted by this project type. Create a new non-portable project to target it".

How to change target on existing projects? Is Newtonsoft compatible with asp.net core?

Comment: Are you trying to target an ASP.NET 4.x project from an ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: I like to use nuget packages which are targeted to 4.x.2 in core 1.0 web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core project can only reference .NET full framework projects indirectly using NuGet packages.